# js How to add href + text onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, autolink

I need to pass (using javascript) text inside span to href

```
<div class='tableCell'><span>information</span></div>
<div class='tableCell'><span>contact</span></div>
<div class='tableCell'><span>about</span></div>
```

for example when i click to about link must be example.com/tag/about/

Comment: I don't see the `href` in your example.

Comment: i know, i need something like this <span onclick='window.location='example.com/CLICKED TEXT/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
 var link = 'http://yousite.com/tag/'+ $(this).text().replace(/ /, "-")+"/";
 window.location.href= link.toLowerCase();
 });
```

---

## DEMO

http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/yNyYPM

Comment: another question.. related to this.. how to replace white space with - in clicked text? for example "about us" must be about-us/ (whit final slash/)

Comment: @VincenzoPiromalli Added that to my answer :)

Comment: mmm... i need slash after clicked text example.com/CLICKED/ ...another question..is it possible to change from A to a in clicked text for example About Us must be about-us/

Comment: @VincenzoPiromalli My answer addresses all of those

Comment: Maybe it's good to convert to lower case and to use `encodeURIComponent` too.

Comment: This will also make *every* span on the page a link

Comment: works everything :) thank you!!! but lower case not, and in wordpress i see 404 error... :(   Anyway thanks to all the same !! P.S. how do I give you the correct answer?

Comment: @vihan1086 that's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: how can i do? I do not find the option !! help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Answer. I'm using Javascript to manipulate the DOM to add a new  element with the href equal to the inner text within the span element.

I hope you find this answer helpful. 
Thanks.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span')
var baseUrl = 'http://example.com/tag/'
for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++)
{
    var curElement = spans[i];
    var parent = curElement.parentElement;
    var newAElement = document.createElement('a');
    var path = baseUrl+curElement.innerHTML;
    newAElement.setAttribute('href', path);
    newAElement.appendChild(curElement);
    parent.appendChild(newAElement)
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonyrod4/0ewd9e3q/)**

Comment: Interesting idea but if you have the parent element you could shorten things up using `innerHTML`. `innerText` might also be better when getting the span's value

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tableCell span").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).text(), // will provide "about"
        href = "http://example.com/tag/"+link; // append to source url
    window.location.href=href; // navigate to the page
});
```

You can try the above code

Answer (score 0):

You do not have links but span in your html. However, you can get build the `href` you want and assign it to an existing link:

```
   $('div.tableCell').click(function(){
        var href = 'example.com/tag/' + $(this).find('span').text();
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets work with pure javascript, I know you want to use jQuery but I am really sure too many people can't do this without looking in to web with pure javascript. So here is a good way.

You can follow it from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p7om90c/)

```
var objectList = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell");

for(var x = 0; x < objectList.length; x++){
    objectList[x].addEventListener('click', function(){
        top.location.href = "example.com/tag/" + this.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    });
}
```

Lets work on the code,

- `var objectList = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell");`
  now we have all element with the class `tableCell`. This is better than `$(".tableCell")` in too many cases.
- Now  `objectList[x].addEventListener('click', function(){});` using this method we added events to each object.
- `top.location.href = "example.com/tag/" + this.childNodes[0].innerHTML;` with this line if somebody clicks to our element with class: We will change the link to his first child node's text.

I hope it is useful, try to work with pure js if you want to improve your self.

Answer (score -1):

#### Your Method

If you always are going to have the url start with something you can do something like this. The way it is set up is...

`prefix` + **THE SPANS TEXT** + `suffix`

spaces in **THE SPANS TEXT** will be converted to **-**

```js
var prefix = 'http://example.com/tag/',
    suffix = '/';

$('span').click(function () {
  window.location.href = prefix + $(this).text().replace(' ', '-').trim().toLowerCase() + suffix;
  //An example is: "http://example.com/tag/about-us/"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='tableCell'><span>Information</span></div>
<div class='tableCell'><span>Contact</span></div>
<div class='tableCell'><span>About</span></div>
```

You can adjust this easily so if you want it to end in `.html` instead of `/`, you can change the suffix. This method will also allow you to make the spans have capitalized words and spaces.

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wahamagoho/1/)

Comment: i need to pass every different clicked text at the end of the url for example: http://example.com/information/ http://example.com/about/

Comment: @VincenzoPiromalli Yes, I fixed and update my answer. It does, `prefix+THE_SPANS_TEXT+suffix`

Comment: abt i cant edit tablecell div and add text :) i need to pass via js only

Comment: Please elaborate on why I have gotten down voted. My answer performs just fine